# First and second tocen regex

Tags: java, regex

How could I get the first and the second text in "" from the string?
I could do it with `indexOf` but this is really boring ((
For example I have a String for parse like: `"aaa":"bbbbb"perhapsSomeOtherText`
And I d like  to get `aaa` and `bbbbb` with the help of Regex pattern - this will help me to use it in switch statement and will greatly simplify my app/

Comment: How about _trying to learn_ regex first before asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all that you have is colon delimited string just split it:

```
String str = ...; // colon delimited
String[] parts = str.split(":");
```

Note, that `split()` receives regex and compilies it every time. To improve performance of  your code you can use `Pattern` as following:

```
private static Pattern pColonSplitter = Pattern.compile(":");

// now somewhere in your code:
String[] parts = pColonSplitter.split(str);
```

If however you want to use pattern for matching and extraction of string fragments in more complicated cases, do it like following:

```
Pattert p = Patter.compile("(\\w+):(\\w+):");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
if (m.find()) {
   String a = m.group(1);
   String b = m.group(2);
}
```

Pay attention on brackets that define *captured group*.

Comment: thank you, I have not know about group(enumerator)! That is really what I need)

Comment: Alex, I have changed the regex to ("(\\w+):(\\d+):"); in order to find strings like "aaa":"123"fdfff but it is not working - what I have done wrong in regex pattern?

Comment: Ok, so the second fragments matches digits only. It does not match your example, but probably this is what you need. So, good luck.

Comment: yes but m.find() is always false in this case(( for example for the string ({"alan":"123"jeff I get m.find() == false with ("(\\w+):(\\d+):" regex((

Comment: It is because of quotes that are a part of your string. You should change regex to `Pattern.compile("\"(\\w+)\":\"(\\d+)\"")`. BUT wait!!! It seems that you are parsing JSON. So, use JSON parser, do not try to re-invent the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

```
String str = "\"aaa\":\"bbbbb\"perhapsSomeOtherText";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"\\w+\""); // word between ""
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
while(m.find()){
   System.out.println(m.group().replace("\"", ""));
}
```

output:

```
aaa
bbbbb
```

Comment: Your code does not compile and even if it would, it gives `":"`.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\"([^\"]*)\"");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("\"aaa\":\"bbbbb\"perhapsSomeOtherText");
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Output

```
aaa
bbbbb
```

Answer (score 0):

there are several ways to do this
Use StringTokenizer or Scanner with UseDelimiter method